# Converting a VCF into a FASTA given a reference with Python, R

Tags: r, python, fasta, vcf, samtools

I am interested in converting a VCF file into a FASTA file given a reference sequence with Python or R.

Samtools/BCFtools (Heng Li) provides a Perl script [`vcfutils.pl`](https://github.com/lh3/samtools/blob/master/bcftools/vcfutils.pl) which does this, the function `vcf2fq` (lines 469-528)

This script has been modified by others to convert InDels as well, e.g. [this](https://github.com/gringer/bioinfscripts/blob/master/vcf2fq.pl) by David Eccles

```
./vcf2fq.pl -f <input.fasta> <all-site.vcf> > <output.fastq>
```

Given that converting a VCF into a FASTA given some reference is a somewhat standard procedure in bioinformatics, are there standard R or Python implementations used by the community?

Comment: I use the pybedtools package which is a wrapper around bedtools. Bedtools will work on VCF files in addition to BED and GTF. Why do you want a Python or R implementation instead of using Heng's solution?

Comment: "Why do you want a Python or R implementation instead of using Heng's solution?" Sometimes it's easier to integrate R code with R code, and Python code with Python

Comment: Based on the name and a quick look at the code, the function you mention produces fastq and not fasta. Do you want fasta or fastq?

Comment: @terdon Either works

Comment: Typically I find using the best tool is more important than what language it was written in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can whip up something quite easily in Python using [pyfaidx](https://github.com/mdshw5/pyfaidx), which allows you to access a FASTA file by genomic coordinates. So you'd just have to pull the coordinates from the VCF to get the sequence, then output in FASTA format with whatever unique identifier for each sequence you want to use.

Edit: The `FastaVariant` class is new in `pyfaidx`, I hadn't seen it before. It makes this even easier, as you won't have to manually mess with the VCF to get the positions. Something like the following should work:

```
consensus = FastaVariant('yourgenome.fasta', 'variants.vcf.gz', het=True, hom=True)

out = open("variants.fasta", "w")

for chrom in consensus.keys:
    for var in consensus[chrom].variants_sites:
        record = consensus[chrom][var-1:var]
        print(record, file=out)

out.close()
```

Comment: Hi Jared, could you expand your answer, with the code to use to perform this? It is my the first time with pyfaidx and I have problems finding how to use it. It seems something like `consensus = FastaVariant('tests/data/chr22.fasta', 'tests/data/chr22.vcf.gz', het=True, hom=True)` should work?

Comment: @Llopis yes, it should be something like that. The `FastaVariant` class is actually new, I wasn't aware it existed, so thanks! I've updated my answer with code I believe should do as intended.

Comment: It seems like `FastaVariant` [ignores indels](https://github.com/mdshw5/pyfaidx/blob/a088141d8c18d0420eb74a1ce1578c3c1ea7ef8f/pyfaidx/__init__.py#L1111).

Answer (score 3):

I tried the `pyfaidx` approach reported by Jared, but I got unhandled exceptions that I could not handle easily within the framework. I had `bcftools` lying around, so I tried [`bcftools consensus`](https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/howtos/consensus-sequence.html) and it worked like a charm. However, you do need an indexed VCF.

```bash
bcftools consensus all-site.vcf.gz < input.fasta > output.fasta
```

NB: `bcftools consensus` has [a few options](https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html#consensus) specified with the `--haplotype` argument for choosing which alleles should be incorporated into the FASTA file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `samtools`-indexed FASTA files for your reference genome, and have [BEDOPS](http://bedops.readthedocs.io) and [htslib](https://github.com/samtools/htslib) installed, you could use [bed2faidxsta.pl](https://gist.github.com/alexpreynolds/fa9b0f90e181e3b4f640) to convert BED to FASTA:

```
$ vcf2bed < variants.vcf | bed2faidxsta.pl --fastaDir=/path/to/fasta > variants.fa
```

To index your FASTA files, you could do the following:

```
$ cd /path/to/fasta
$ bgzip -c my_genome.fa > my_genome.fa.bgz
$ samtools faidx my_genome.fa.bgz
```

Comment: Thank you. This wouldn't be too difficult to convert into Python/R, but I'm asking for scripts which have this already completed.

Comment: If you have Python available, you very probably already have Perl. In any case, you can use `system` in R to call external scripts (written in any language). See `?system` for more details.