# How to convert VCF format file into Fasta(.fa) with the Reference data

Tags: fasta, sequence-analysis

I need a Software or Python Program for Converting VCF(.vcf) to  FASTA(.fa) format with the help of reference (.fa)

Comment: Not quite a dupe since it asks for an R or python approach, but very relevant: [Converting a VCF into a FASTA given a reference with Python, R](//bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/2825).

Comment: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/converting-a-vcf-into-a-fasta-given-a-reference-with-python-r

Comment: Also vcftools..

Answer (score 2):

I used [FastaAlternateReferenceMaker](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/tooldocs/3.8-0/org_broadinstitute_gatk_tools_walkers_fasta_FastaAlternateReferenceMaker.php) previously. You will need to download [GATK](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/download/) first. Next you prepare your reference genome (reference.fasta) and your vcf file (input.vcf). You will call the GATK function like this:

```
 java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
   -T FastaAlternateReferenceMaker \
   -R reference.fasta \
   -o output.fasta \
   -V input.vcf \
```

output.fasta will contain the new fasta with snps inserted at sites specific by the vcf file

Comment: I got this error when I used gatk on a Linux plaftorm:

A USER ERROR has occurred: Input files reference and features have incompatible contigs: No overlapping contigs found.

Comment: your chromosome names are different

Comment: how do I resolve this please? 

Additionally, the vcf files are from somewhere external and I actually subset it to get a specific sample. my reference is https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/H_sapiens/annotation/GRCh38_latest/refseq_identifiers/GRCh38_latest_genomic.fna.gz